# parse.com backend How to list stored files

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform

I'm using parse as my backend and would like to use the rest api to store files.
I've already successfully tested creating new data with the curl request here https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#files Now I would like to see what files I have on my parse.
I don't see any view for these in the data browser. Maybe there's a way to get a listing via a get request? How do I list the files stored on my parse backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the  column type in the parse data browser will be 'file' denoting 'pointer to a file in the parse CDN'....

treat that like a third party CDN where you also, do not have the 'fileList' capability u ask 4.

live with what u get from the parse browser's inclusion of the pointer, click the field in the browser and , depend on your OS/browser/plugins, it will automatic download/play the file depending on the MIME type you supplied in the headers when u uploaded it.

Remember that you can use the parse dashboard to ask it to delete or GC any files no longer pointed to by active class.rows.

IMO - its not hard to live without what you've asked for as long as you know the other features parse includes with these file type pointers/ refs.

Comment: could you clarify? I see no `file` column in any of my tables in data browser. I haven't associated the uploaded files with any objects yet. Maybe that's what you're refering to?

Comment: yeah. there is no browser from parse on the raw file POSTs.  You only see them after other parse classes objects are created which point to the files. Then , in the browser for those secondary classes, there will be a 'type' on the pointer col and it will be 'file'.